# Wifite Not Working

Tags: kali-linux

First when i open wifite it was showing "No device select or wireless card" then i search that problem on internet and i got solution that to download Compact wireless for kali linux version"26 june 2016" i download that extract that and load it and it was done.Then i start wifite again and it was showing two option i select option 1 and 2 many times but it is on loop and again wifite ask me to select device to put on monitor.
Now i search that problem on internet a person say to stop network manager service i also  did that but it is say problem.

[image: Image of wifite asking again for device to put on monitior]

Answer (score 0):

I got wifite working; what I did was type:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

after that I again open wifite and it is scanning devices.
But i want to ask if a router don't have Wps and is Wpa or Wpa2 then can wifite can crack that network???